# Install R (Project for Statistical Computing) on iPhone 5 / iPad 4th generation (ARM v7s instruction set)

Tags: ios, r, ios6, iphone-5, armv7

I have a jailbroken (evasi0n) 4th generation iPad, with iOS 6.1.2 firmware.

Following [this](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=getting-started:installation:iphone) tutorial, I've tried to install R on the iPad.
I've added this repository in Cydia
http://leafmoon.users.sourceforge.net/cydia/./
and I've installed *R the statistical language* package.

Installation completes successfully, without any problem.
But when in Mobile Terminal I type:

```
R
```

I get

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I'm quite sure the problem is the same type of the one explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710849/get-gnu-c-compiler-working-on-ios-6-x), that is the package does not provide ARMv7s support.

Clearly, R can be installed manually, but I don't know how this can be done in this specific case.
Following documentation cited above, I read the build dependencies that have to be installed for R are:

*gettext, pcre, readline, png, tiff, x11*

and

*com.ech0chrome.libbz2, com.ech0chrome.libjpeg, com.ech0chrome.xzutils, com.ech0chrome.libgfortran, com.ech0chrome.iphone-gccplus*

I think the *Illegal instruction: 4* error is due to (at least) one of these last .deb files, that has to be re-compiled for ARMv7s.
But unfortunately my knowledge for this issue ends here: that's why I'm asking your help.

How can I re-compile this .deb files?
Are there other solutions in order to install R on iOS devices with Apple A6/A6X Chip?

**P.S.**
1) I've [GNU C Compiler](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.de/2013/02/illegal-instruction-4.html) correctly installed on iPad.
2) I'm an iOS developer, so I've XCode (v. 4.5) installed on my machine.
3) In my iPhone 4S (iOS 5.1.1) R is working properly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why R on an iPad?  (I'm asking truly respectfully, not being able to find any compelling reason to go through the trouble - other than the technical challenge).

Comment: Reason is very simple: I use R in my daily job, and I would like to be able to perform some of these calculations on my iPad, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have gnu sed in iOS, you should patch R 2.x (after installation in A6/A6X CPU such as iPhone 5 / iPad 4 and also A7 CPU such as iPhone 5s / iPad Air / iPad Mini Retina) as below

```
sed -i'' 's/\x00\x30\x93\xe4/\x00\x30\x93\xe5/g;s/\x00\x30\xd3\xe4/\x00\x30\xd3\xe5/g;' /usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```

R 3.0.2 package is now here http://code.google.com/p/apiexplorer/downloads/detail?name=RPackage.tgz

Answer (score 1):

A better approach may be to have an R sever of some sort running on another computer and access that from your iPad rather than trying to run R directly on the iPad.  Rstudio has a server available and googling for Rstudio and iPad brings up several discussions (some with problems that may or may not have been fixed so far), but you will probably have more people to work with and more hope of success that way.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your reply. Yes, I agree with you, a server-based solution would be the simplest one. I already use RStudio Server in my daily job and I know is a great way to work with R, but I'd like to be able to run R locally on my iPad 4th gen, and I hope this is possible as is possible on pre-A6/A6X chip iOS devices.

Comment: I tried this out, and it works partially: I can connect to rstudio server, type code in the console, visualize charts, manage files, etc. The only thing that is not working is typing code in the file window (which is obviously a big limitation). I hope this bug will be fixed soon.